# Eclipse RCP Tycho - Unzip the exported product

Tags: eclipse, maven, build, rcp, tycho

We have automated our Eclipse RCP build using Maven/Tycho. The exported zip, that contains all our product's files, is located under ../target/ in the project's folder. However we'd like to automatically unzip the zip file and (if possible) move it to another build directory. So the current file structure looks like this:

```
SampleProject
|__target
   |__SampleProduct.zip
```

and we would like to have it like this:

```
C
|__Export
   |__SampleProject
      |_SampleProduct (unzipped)
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

The `tycho-p2-director-plugin` already creates what you are looking for, in the `materialize-products` step, right before the `archive-products` step that creates the ZIP files.

You will find the unzipped products below `target/product/$productId/$os/$ws/$arch`, e.g., in `target/product/org.example.product/linux/gtk/x86_64`.